# zsh uses command flag as directory?

Tags: terminal, zsh

When I run:

`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0`

I get

`zsh: no such user or named directory: 1.0`

I'm 99% sure there is something obvious I'm missing but I'm not really proficient in these kind of things and I found this one hard to Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A word `~foo` expands to the absolute path to the home directory of the user *foo*, hence `~1.0` searches for the home directory of user *1.0*. If you want to avoid this interpretation, just quote the parameter: `'~1.0'`.